# primeng filter location for last column

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have an issue with filter dropdown option on angular UI application which is using primeng. The problem is when I click on filter on the Status column, filter is appearing before 'Balance Exclusion Used' column. The same code is working perfectly for the filter present not on last column. Here in  my case 'Status' column is last column and the filter should align to the Status column. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will get more useful answers if you post a minimal example.

Comment: Hi Simon.. It is I believe css stuff that I have to include which I am not sure..